# Getting PID of queue in Horizon with Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-8, laravel-horizon

For different reasons I need to read the PID of the queues of a supervisor in Laravel Horizon. The problem is that I can't find the information in the library.

I'm able to retrieve all supervisor like this:

```
public function index(SupervisorRepository $supervisors){
    $supervisors = collect($supervisors->all())->sortBy('name');
    return $supervisors;
}
```

or all workload (queue) like this:

```
public function index(WorkloadRepository $workloadRepository){
    $workload = collect($workloadRepository->get())->sortBy('name')->values()->toArray();
    return $workload;
}
```

but I don't see how I can get the PID of queue by the repository, last but not least I can't run shell command on my server so I must get it by either accessing Redis or Laravel Horizon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out you can't get it from horizon, you need to get it by questioning your os